# Android create custom key "@hotmail.com","@gmail.com"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

could create a customized key on the keyboard with the list of words that I want?

I have installed the keyboard "SwiftKey X" and when I position myself in a text field, I get a key on the keyboard android "@..." and I get to select the options ("@hotmail.com", "@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com").

I wonder if you can program this list and if you can add domains
custom as "dyndns.com", "no-ip.com".

is posible?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean specifically SwiftKeyX's keyboard, or do you mean a custom keyboard in general?

Comment: in general, to create from android.

Comment: Then certainly. In addition to the link the answer below provided, take a look at the softkeyboard sample included in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create a custom keyboard for the soft display. Here is a link that discusses it on the android development site.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
<Key
                android:horizontalGap="1.1%p"
                android:keyLabel="GMAIL"
                android:keyOutputText="GMAIL"
                android:keyWidth="10.0%p" />
```